# macOS, exfat 3.5 hdd recognizes in one external enclosure, says not recognized and to initialize in other (no thanks), what could be the cause?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, ntfs, exfat

I have a single bay enclosure that I initialized an 8tb drive in as exfat in, then I got a 5 bay enclosure, when I stick it in the 5 bay it's not recognized and says to initialize.

I put it back in the single bay and it works perfectly fine, same computer, same OS

I misplaced the oem usb type b cable that came with the 5 bay, but I have many others, and the proper ac, and other drives connect and are recognized with various cables.

Another possibility is that maybe it doesn't like mix and match drive formats, as I have some ntfs and that one is exfat (I'm going to convert them all to ntfs eventually).

Any ideas? It's not a huge issue but would prefer to be able to ditch the single bay.

Comment: Not an answer, because I don't know how to fix it short of reformatting. Some enclosures 'fake' the data block size for compatibility with older machines. Move the drive to an enclosure that doesn't do this & all the partitions appears to be misaligned.

Comment: I see, I can plug into same pc and transfer to another drive I suppose, then reformat the empty in the new enclosure and it might recognize it.

Comment: If you've time, drive space & patience, yes, that will be the simple but tedious fix; copy off, reformat, copy back. I know the partitions can be re-aligned by putting the "correct" numbers in, but I have *absolutely* no clue how to do it, I'm afraid - hence not posting this as an answer, in the hope someone who did know would join in.

Comment: turns out the 5 bay was real garbage, it actually screwed up a drive I had badly simply by inserting so that it could only be partially recovered with recovery software which I didn't bother with, good thing I didn't care what was on it and was ok with formatting it anyway, I've had problems with that company before, I returned and got a 4 bay from a company I've had better experiences with.